Calling Asr model in BHasini throws - {"code":"something went wrong","message":null,"timestamp":"2024-07-03T06:08:52.407+00:00"}
I am trying to call the asr model of bhasini  api to get transcription of my audio.
I tried the following code.
import requests
import json

url = "https://meity-auth.ulcacontrib.org/ulca/apis/v0/model/getModelsPipeline"

payload = {
  "pipelineTasks": [
    {
      "taskType": "asr",
      "config": {
        "language": {
          "sourceLanguage": "kn"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "pipelineRequestConfig": {
            "pipelineId" : "64392f96daac500b55c543cd"
        }
  }
headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "userID": "",
        "ulcaApiKey": "1"
    }

response = requests.post('https://meity-auth.ulcacontrib.org/ulca/apis/v0/model/getModelsPipeline', json=payload, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    response_data = response.json()

    service_id = response_data["pipelineResponseConfig"][0]["config"][0]["serviceId"]
    print(service_id)

payload = {
  "pipelineTasks" : [
    {
        "taskType" : "asr",
        "language": {
                    "sourceLanguage": "hi"
                },
        "serviceId": service_id,
        "audioFormat": "flec",
        "samplingRate": 16000
    }
],
  "inputData": {
    "audio": [
      {
        "audioContent":"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"
      }
    ]
  }
}




response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, json=payload)

print(response.text)


Output
ai4bharat/conformer-multilingual-dravidian-gpu--t4
{"code":"something went wrong","message":null,"timestamp":"2024-07-03T06:08:52.407+00:00"}
